# Cannot resolve symbol ErrorListener

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm trying to set up volley to pull down this JSONObject from iTunes

```
String url = "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=michael+jackson";
```

The whole point is to parse the object to get the album art url for a particular song

So I set this code up to get the JsonObject, and I'm getting a couple of errors

```
Cannot resolve symbol ErrorListener
Cannot resolve symbol Listener
```

Here is the code with annotated errors

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
        (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Downloader.Response.Listener // Cannot resolve symbol Listener
                <JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                // the response is already constructed as a JSONObject!
                try {
                    response = response.getJSONObject("args");
                    String site = response.getString("site"),
                            network = response.getString("network");
                    System.out.println("Site: "+site+"\nNetwork: "+network);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Downloader.Response.ErrorListener // Cannot resolve symbol ErrorListener
                () {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(jsonRequest);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Response.ErrorListener

http://afzaln.com/volley/com/android/volley/Response.ErrorListener.html

There is no Downloader.ResposneListener

Answer (score 1):

**Change TO**

> StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(DownloadManager.Request.Method.GET, url,

to

> StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(com.android.volley.Request.Method.GET, url,

**Your code will be**

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
    (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new com.android.volley.Response.Listener // CHANGES HERE
            <JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            // the response is already constructed as a JSONObject!
            try {
                response = response.getJSONObject("args");
                String site = response.getString("site"),
                        network = response.getString("network");
                System.out.println("Site: "+site+"\nNetwork: "+network);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener // CHANGES HERE
            () {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(jsonRequest);